# Spark scala CSV write with option escape and quote together breaks CSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The Input is Below:

| Name | Text |
| --- | --- |
| A' | D,John |
| B | "AB |
| C | A"B" |
| D | This is "78-DC-DF-001"20 23:11:01 - 12323 |

I am using the below code to write the above data into a CSV file(output is dataframe which contain the input data):

```
output.coalesce(1).write
.format("csv")
.option("escape","")
.option("quote","")
.save("Output")
```

When I am using only the escape option then Output is like below which is not proper:

| Name | Text |
| --- | --- |
| A' | D,John |
| B | "AB"" |
| C | A""B"""" |
| D | This is ""78-DC-DF-001""20 23:11:01 - 12323"" |

And when I use both escape and quote together then it is shifting the comma values like below:

| Name | Text |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A' | D | John |
| B | "AB |  |
| C | A"B" |  |
| D | This is "78-DC-DF-001"20 23:11:01 - 12323 |  |

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue in spark scala. Require the same input as output.

Comment: It's not clear how you read and process your data before writing to the output. And no clue to the type of `output` variable. As I can see, you have not set the delimiter or if you have headers included in the input. The default delimiter is a comma, which explains your last output separated by commas.

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa I have read the data from the CSV file and stored that into the Output data frame and I am writing this data frame into a CSV file.  I am doing this experiment because I have a large big dataset and that has similar kinds of values in different columns. Here I am not Processing anything in between reading and writing the data frame but this practice will clear the issue. I am writing the CSV file here so the delimiter I haven't mention because default is comma.

Comment: Use tab to separator.